# Extracting a paragraph from articles | Regular Expression

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have scraped several articles concerning terrorist attacks. From these articles I would like to extract a specific paragraph.

This is a sample of the articles scraped:

```
By   DAVID D. KIRKPATRICK    MARCH 18, 2015 
Scenes from Tunisian state television showed confusion outside an art museum and Parliament on Wednesday after gunmen attacked.
CAIRO — Gunmen in military uniforms killed 19 people on Wednesday in a
midday attack on a museum in downtown Tunis, dealing a new blow to the tourist industry 
that is vital to  Tunisia  as it struggles to consolidate the only transition to democracy 
after the Arab Spring revolts. 
Tunisian officials had initially said that the attackers took 10
hostages and killed nine people, including seven foreign visitors and two Tunisians.
```

What I want to extract for further analysis, is the text that goes, in this example, from: "CAIRO —" to the first fullstop.

[This is the regular expression](https://regex101.com/r/0DRayP/3) that I came up with:

```
([A-Z]+(?:\W+\w+)?)\s*—[\s\S]+\.\s
```

With this regular expression I extract only the starting point of the paragraph but I don't extract the rest of it.

Comment: Is the regex extracting more or less than you want it to? (my suspicion is that it extracts too much because you didn't use a lazy [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)).

Comment: You're right. I am trying to extrac only the first paragraph starting after the capitalized word and the sign — . When I apply it to whole dataset I extract too much

Comment: It's confusing - you specify "to the first fullstop." and that's what you get. What is i t you really want?

Comment: I added other articles in the sample, the link will show you more articles, and when I apply it I retrieve everything instead of the paragraph for each article

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use non-greedy

```
(([A-Z]+(?:\W+\w+)?)\s*—[\s\S]+?\.\s)
```

The `?` after a `+` (or `*`) makes it non-greedy. Meaning it will only match as little as possible, instead of normal behaviour, where it matches as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT1:**

try the regex as follows:

```
([A-Z]+\w+\s*—\s*.*?\.)
```

---

It is about grouping, though it matches the text that you want.

try the following regex (surround the regex with parenthisis):

```
(([A-Z]+(?:\W+\w+)?)\s*—[\s\S]+\.\s)
```

Group 1 contains the required string/text.

Image reference:
[image]

Comment: The problem is that when I apply the regex to the whole dataset, I extract too much information. I also tried to split the text in separated articles but it does not work

Comment: does that mean it matches multiple times/groups? can we hard code CAIRO? can you update the code, with the actual issue?

Comment: Just use a non-greedy version! `(([A-Z]+(?:\W+\w+)?)\s*—[\s\S]+?\.\s)`. See the `?` after the `+`

Comment: I can't use it, cause there are several article written from different cities

Comment: Thanks @Fallenhero can you please explain me